# Does a closed right ideal of a C$^*$-algebra have a C$^*$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

$A$ is an infinite dimensional C$^*$-algebra and $J\subset A$ is a closed right ideal. $A$ and $J$ are infinite dimensional(as a vector space). I want to find an **infinite** dimensional C$^*$-algebra **subset of $J$**. How can I find it?

I know an infinite dimensional C$^*$-algebra has an infinite dimensional commutative C$^*$-subalgebra. So if $A_1$ is infinite dimensional commutative C$^*$-subalgebra of $A$, Is the set $A_1\cap J$ an infinite dimensional C$^*$-algebra? If no, so what can I do?

Comment: What is $I$ in your first paragraph?

Comment: Execuse me for my mistake

Comment: No worries.  Well in general if $J$ is a one-sided ideal, then $J\cap J^*$ is a two-sided ideal, hence a $C^*$-subalgebra, although I am not sure if there is any satisfying criteria for determining whether or not this ideal is infinite-dimensional, or even non-trivial.

Comment: But if $J=\{ f\in B(\ell^2): f^*((1,0,0,0,\ldots ))=0 \} \subseteq B(\ell^2)$ then $J\cap J^* $ isn't an two sided ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in general. Many C$^*$-algebras are simple. In such a case if $B\subset J$ is a C$^*$-algebra, then 
$$
B=B\cap B^*\subset J\cap J^*=\{0\}, 
$$
since $J\cap J^*$ is a closed ideal.

Comment: Why $J\cap J^*=0$ ?    $J\cap J^*$ is a two sided ideal of $J$ and not a two sided ideal of $A$, So why $J\cap J^*=0$

Comment: But if J is simple then $J\cap J^*=0$. Is there an infinite dimensional simple closed right ideal for ecah infinite dimensional $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: I don't really follow what you are saying; a right ideal is not an algebra, so what does "$J $ is simple" mean, and what would "ideal of $J $ mean?    And, again, if $J $ is a right ideal of $A $, then $ J^*\cap J $ is a bilateral ideal of  $A $.

Comment: Why $J\cap J^*$ is a two sided ideal of A?

Comment: a right ideal is not an algebra?! So I think I made some mistakes.  Excuse me

Comment: It is an algebra; but we are talking C$^*$-algebras here, so "being an algebra" is usually not relevant, and when I say "algebra" or "subalgebra" I mean C$^*$.

Comment: As for $J\cap J^*$, if $x\in J\cap J^*$ and $J$ is a right ideal, then $xa\in J$ and $ax=(x^*a^*)^*\in J^*$. Then $xa=(a^*x^*)^*\in J^*$, so bilateral.

Comment: Thank you.     thank you

Comment: Also, right ideals are very common, if you take $a$ with no right inverse then $\overline{aA}$ is a proper right ideal.

Comment: Thank you for all your guidance.    But if $J$ is a right ideal of a C$^*$-algebra $A$, then  we can't say $J\cap J^*$ is a two sided ideal of $A$;  but it is always a left ideal of $J$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.